# Turing instability: Whats the background of this special approach?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The idea of Turing instability is that diffusion can cause instability. If we have the system
$$
u_t=\Delta u+\gamma f(u,v),\qquad v_t=d\Delta v+\gamma g(u,v)
$$
on $(0,a), a>0$ and with zero flux conditions, let $(u_0,v_0)$ be an equilibrium that is stable at the absence of diffusion ($\gamma=0$). Now, consider the full system ($\gamma\neq 0$). Linearizing the system in $(u_0,v_0)$, i.e. $w=(w_1,w_2)$ with $w_1=u-u_0, w_2=v-v_0$, we get the system
$$
(w_1)_t=\Delta w_1+\gamma(f_u(u_0,v_0)w_1+f_v(u_0,v_0)w_2),\\(w_2)_t=d\Delta w_2+\gamma(g_u(u_0,v_0)w_1+g_v(u_0,v_0)w_2).~~~(*)
$$
Now, in the literature I found, the following approach is made:

$$
w(x,t)=\sum_k c_k e^{\lambda(k)t}W_k(x)~~~(**)
$$
where $W_k(x)$ are eigenfunctions belonging to the eigenvalue problem
$$
\Delta W+k^2W=0.
$$

> > I do not really understand where the approach $(**)$ and the eigenvalue problem come from. In some sense, this reminds me on *separation of variables* in the following way: If we consider, for example, 
> >     $$
> > (w_1)_t=\Delta w_1
> > $$
> >     and make the separation of variables ansatz, i.e. $w_1(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then one gets
> >     $$
> > X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)\Leftrightarrow \frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-k^2=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}
> > $$
> >     so that we get the two equations
> >     $$
> > T'=-k^2T,\qquad X''+k^2W=0.
> > $$
> >     Solving this, we get
> >     $$
> > w_1(x,t)=\sum_k c_k\exp(-k^2t)W_k(x),~~W_k(x)=c\cdot\cos\left(\frac{kx}{a}\right).
> > $$
> >     For $w_2(x,t)$ one should get something similar, since the only difference is that we have the factor $d$. So the approach $(**)$ seems to come from solving 
> >     $$
> > (w_1)_t=\Delta w_1,\qquad (w_2)_t=d\Delta w_2.~~~(***)
> > $$
> >     by separation of variables. Is that possible? But why should a solution of $(***)$ be an appropriate approach for a solution of the full system $(*)$?

Many greetings

Comment: Can anyone translate "ansatz" ? I think, this word is only existent in the german language. I am not sure, whether "approach" is the proper translation.

Comment: @Peter Sorry, thought ansatz is used in English language, too. I think approach is a good translation and I changed it in my question.

Answer (score 4):

1. "ansatz" is an educated guess and is a perfectly valid word in the English language literature.
2. The eigenvalue problem
   $$
   -\Delta W=k^2 W
   $$
   with the corresponding boundary conditions is known to have infinitely many eigenfunctions that are *complete*, i.e., any other function that satisfies the same boundary conditions can be represented as a Fourier series through $W_k$. Moreover, $W_k$ are orthogonal, which simplifies tons of the following computations.

Ok, here some more details.

Consider problem
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f(u),\quad u_x(t,0)=u_x(t,\pi)=0.
$$
Let $u=0$ be an equilibrium, then the linearized system is
$$
u_t=u_{xx}+f'(0)u.
$$
Consider the eigenproblem
$$
-w''=k^2 w,\quad w_x(0)=w_x(\pi)=0
$$
and look for the solution of the linearized problem in the form
$$
u(t,x)=\sum c_k(t)w_k(x).
$$
Now, you have
$$
\sum c_k'(t)w_k=\sum c_k(t)w''_k(x)+f'(0)\sum c_kw_k
$$
now multiply left and right hand sides by $w_m$, integrate and use orthogonality.

Comment: I still do not see thy the ansatz is appropriate for the full system when its origin is from a reduced system.

Comment: Its origin is from linearized system.

Comment: Which linearized system? Sorry, could you please explain that a bit more detailed? For me its not clear.

Comment: Maybe you mean the linearized system which I named $(*)$? But how do I make the separation ansatz with $(*)$?

Comment: @Rhjg I added a couple of lines, but still invite you to finish the reasonings.

Comment: My problem is, I do not know how to make the separation ansatz for example for your $u_t=u_{xx}+f'(0)u$ or, even worse, for something like $(*)$.

Comment: You do not need to. I added two more lines, but if you cannot conclude from here, you should pick up a textbook.

Comment: Then my problem is the following: I still do not see why we can just say "consider the eigenvalue problem $W''+k^2W=0$ and look for the solution of the linearized problem in the form $u(t,x)=\sum c_k(t)w_k(x)$". For me this falls out of the clouds and I would like to understand where this strategy does come from.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, but: For which kind of pde is it appropriate to start with $W''+k^2W=0$? You wrote that the $w_k$ form a base, so to say, and that ANY other function that satisfies the boundary conditions can be expressed by these $w_k$: But for which kind of PDE does this hold?

Comment: Any problem of the form $u_t=\Delta u+f(u),$ with some given boundary conditions, where $u$ is a vector, can be attacked by using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the corresponding eigenproblem for the Laplace operator.

Comment: Even if $f(u,v)$ and not only $f(u)$?

Comment: Please read "where $u$ is a vector"

Comment: Can you give me a link where I can read about this?

Comment: E.g., [Spatial Ecology via Reaction-Diffusion Equations](http://www.amazon.com/Spatial-Ecology-via-Reaction-Diffusion-Equations/dp/0471493015/ref=sr_1_8?ie=UTF8&qid=1450922019&sr=8-8&keywords=spatial+ecology)

Comment: @Artem. How do we get this Eigenvalue problem, where does it come from?

Comment: @H.Hawks Use the separation of variables for the linearized problem.

Comment: for the homogenous equation? i.e. $w_t=\Delta w$?

Comment: @H.Hawks No, as I said, for the linearized problem: $u_t=u_{xx}+f'(0)u$